# Please help to understand what are a curly braces here for -> { signal }?

Tags: javascript, curly-braces

What means curly braces around signal?

```
const controller = new AbortController();
const signal = controller.signal;
readFile(fileInfo[0].name, **{ signal }**, (err, buf) => {
...
```

Thanks.

Comment: It's shorthand for an object where the key and the value are the same: `{ signal: signal }` can be written as `{ signal }`

Comment: @Nick Nitpick: key _name_ and the value variable _name_, not key and value. (Key and value would be same with `{ [signal]: signal }`, or `{ signal: "signal" }`; if `signal` is e.g. `"foo"`, `{ signal }` results in `{ "signal": "foo" }`, with key and value demonstrably not same.)

Answer (score 1):

If you read [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback) you'll note that the second argument to `readfile` is `options` which is an [**object**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics), one property of which is `signal`.

Answer (score 1):

In **ES6/ES2015** It's an [object **property value shorthand**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#property_definitions):

if you have a variable named `signal`

```
const signal = "test"
const ob = {signal};
console.log(ob.signal); // "test"
```

is equal to ES5's

```
const signal = "test"
const ob = {signal: signal};
console.log(ob.signal); // "test"
```